# Changing style of elements in nested divs

Tags: html, css

Here's an HTML page with some styling.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        span {
            color: #FFF;
        }
        .light-gray span {
            background-color: #AAA;
        }
        .dark-gray span {
            background-color: #666;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="light-gray">
        <span>Text on light-gray background</span>
        <div class="dark-gray">
            <span>Text on dark-gray background</span>
            <div class="light-gray">
                <span>Text on light-gray background again</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="dark-gray">
            <span>More text on dark-gray background</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The goal is to create multi-level structure so that elements of each level use one of two color schemes, light gray and dark gray in the example above. First level is light gray, second is dark-gray, third is light-gray again, and so on. The problem is that 3rd level `span` which is supposed to be light gray is actually dark gray. How should I change CSS for this page to achieve my goal?

**UPD**: Elements in styled div may be in containers that don't change color scheme, like:

```html
<div class="dark-gray">
    <div>
        <div>
            <span>Text on dark-gray background</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="light-gray">
        <div>
            <span>Text on light-gray background again</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: add a second class to overide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you assign styles to the span itself:

```
span.light-gray { background-color: #AAA; }
span.dark-gray { background-color: #666; }
```

And update HTML to:

```
<div>
    <span class="light-gray">Text on light-gray background</span>
    <div>
        <span class="dark-gray">Text on dark-gray background</span>
        <div>
            <span class="light-gray">Text on light-gray background again</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="dark-gray">More text on dark-gray background</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This one may work: though it requires marking all these elements on page with these classes, CSS will remain compact. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have add two more combination in your CSS.

```
    span {
        color: #FFF;
    }
    .light-gray span {
        background-color: #AAA;
    }
    .dark-gray span {
        background-color: #666;
    }
    .light-gray .dark-gray span {
        background-color: #666;
    }
    .dark-gray .light-gray span {
        background-color: #AAA;
    }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5e95X/)

Comment: It works but I have about 20 styles that depend on this. If I duplicate all these styles code maintenance will become significantly harder, so I'd like something more elegant. Also I can't join them using commas, it doesn't work in this case.

Comment: mark comma separate wont work.Because the order is important here. If you want more elegant solution, you need to use jquery only.

Answer (score 0):

Added second class to override see the below example

```
<div class="light-gray dark-gray">
                <span>Text on light-gray background again</span>
            </div>
```

In css the priority goes to last added class so it class dark-gray override the class light-gray

Comment: No, I need this span to be LIGHT gray, not overriden by dark-gray class.

Comment: that is not possible in css go to jquery

Answer (score 0):

second class is ovveride becoze u are wrong selection dom element using css
see the below code for css

```
        .light-gray > span {
            background-color: #AAA;
        }
        .dark-gray > span {
            background-color: #666;
        }
```

Comment: Elements may also be in containers that don't change color scheme. I'll add it to question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a CSS Combinators like + > ~

code:

```
  <style type="text/css">
    span {
        color: #FFF;
    }
    .light-gray >span {
        background-color: #AAA;
    }
    .dark-gray >span {
        background-color: #666;
    }
 </style>
```

depending on the relationship between the selector

Comment: I don't see how + and ~ will help. > will affect only direct children of styles div, but I need it to affect elements on any depth (until scheme is changed).

Comment: + and ~ may not help in your case but > will.It affects nested elements also.Just check with your code